# MySQL: Update a SET field using named value and bit-operator

Tags: mysql, sql-update, bitwise-operators

For MySQL, is it possible to update a field of type SET using one of the field's named values and bitwise operators?
Example:

Assume `foo` to be `SET('a', 'b',...)`,
then the following does not work:

```
UPDATE mytable SET foo = foo | 'a' WHERE ...
```

Apparently, only `foo = 'a'` or `foo = foo | 1` work. Is there any trick to get the above example working and make MySQL be aware of `'a'` being not a "normal" string? I'd like to avoid magic numbers... Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE mytable SET foo = CONCAT_WS(',', foo, 'a') WHERE ...
```

Comment: Thanks! I knew there must be a "dirty" hack.